# modular frontend support? /new features, xbox controller support?

Tags: modeling, animation

Both my brother and I have tried to use blender in the past for 3D modeling or animation.  I found the layout/ all the keyboard cammands frustrating.  Lately within the past months, my brother has spent 3 weeks on and off trying to learn from video tutorials on the web.

I had some ideas to make it easier to use...

One thing that may make it easier to use may be if a person is able to use a game controller or other input devices to create animations.  Is this possible currently? not BGE

After trying to work through web video tutorials for blender3d, I eventually used freecad for 3Dprinting and was able to create and print basic 3D shapes.

Is there any way to make the blender GUI feel like freecad?

Comment: Blender is infamously know for not being user friendly or welcoming to new users, but I strongly doubt using a game controller to create animations would be any easier.

Comment: Please only ask one question at a time. You are welcome to ask as many questions as you need as separate posts.